# ListView Set Checked Item Background color

Tags: android, list

I have designed a two pane UI for Table. In left pane I am showing List View and in Right pane I am showing List Details. I want to show the list row as selected on which the user clicks and show its display in right Pane.

So I am setting below code to make item selected.

```
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
 android:background="@drawable/selector_list_view"
```

The list layout is in below layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_dialog_fragment">


    <Button     
        android:id="@+id/SortByTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_black"
        android:background="@drawable/sort_button_selected"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/project"
        android:drawablePadding="5dip"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/up_arrow"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SortByDate" 
        android:textColor="@color/solid_black"
        android:background="@drawable/sort_button_unselected"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:drawablePadding="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:text="@string/due_date"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:paddingRight="1dp"        
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
    style="@style/title_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SortOrder"
    android:text="@string/workflow_incourt" />

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SearchFooter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewTitle"
    android:background="@color/solid_white"
   >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewProject"
        style="@style/listview_style"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_list_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the drawable is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark"/>
<item android:state_checkable="true" android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark"/>
```

But still it is not showing the list row as selected. What more I need to do to achieve this.

Also attached is the screen shot for the selected item. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can keep trace of your item ID selected in just one variable. Then in:

- GetView of your adapter if the ID matches with the stored one you set for example red color
- OnListItemClickListener you erase old ID by substituting it with the new ID ref